# How do you create a counter columnfamily with CQL3 in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

How do you create a counter columnfamily with CQL3 in cassandra?

I used to use:
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY userstats (username varchar PRIMARY KEY, images counter) WITH default_validation=counter AND comment='User Stats';

Now when i run that in CQL3 i get:
Bad Request: default_validation is not a valid keyword argument for CREATE COLUMNFAMILY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CQL3 no longer sticks with the "dynamic column names" model. It can still make arbitrarily wide cassandra rows, but they look like "normal" narrow tables in CQL, with all columns named and defined. This is why CQL3 no longer supports setting a `default_validation` or `comparator`, etc.

You should read and understand http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1 before doing anything nontrivial in CQL3.

The answer to your question, though, is that it's as simple as leaving off the `default_validation`:

```
CREATE TABLE userstats (
    username varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    images counter
) WITH comment='User Stats';
```

Although it's not clear whether you intended to use multiple counters per row there, since you wanted a `default_validation`. If you did, and your `comparator` would have been `varchar`, you could do:

```
CREATE TABLE userstats (
    username varchar,
    countername varchar,
    value counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, countername)
) WITH comment='User Stats';
```

..and let `images` just be one of the counternames.

Comment: I attempted to use your recommended command from a CQL3 prompt and get: TSocket read 0 bytes

Comment: In my experience, cqlsh is lagging behind features. You should try using directly thrift execute_cql

Comment: @Alar cqlsh doesn't lag behind in cql features, because the actual cql processing is done on the Cassandra side. Cqlsh just helps make the output look pretty and provides nice tab completion and readline functionality. It's using the same thrift call.

Comment: @mithrix are you using Cassandra 1.1.0? There is a bug which keeps proper counter tables from being created with cql. 1.1.1 is a bugfix release; you should upgrade to that.

Comment: @the paul, Sorry I got the wrong impression some parsing was implemented at python level

Comment: @Alar it does do some parsing in Python, but just to provide the tab completion and other incidental features. If the parsing fails (new syntax or whatever), it will still pass on the query to Cassandra.

Comment: Looks indeed a robust approach :)

Comment: @the paul can you give us any example of using counter columns(insertion specific)